# Passing variables between 2 VueJS components in Laravel not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Laravel page with 2 Vue JS components, loaded in a app.js file.

But I do not understand why passing variables between my components is not working.

This is my core app.js:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

My **results component**:

```
props: ['url', 'email'],
data: function () {
    return {
      items: []
    }
},
mounted() {
    axios.post(this.url, { email: this.email }).then((response) => {
      this.items = reponse.data;
    })
```

But how can I update this items with another parameter (= email)?
I don't understand how I can access this component.

I have tried:

```
// Form Vue component
this.$emit('updateResults', email)
```

But thats not working. How can I update my results vue component?

Comment: You are missing some parts. Where are the components used? $emit just works to notify the "parent". You can try to use a EventBus if you need to talk across your app. See here an example: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-global-event-bus

Comment: I did try that with: EventBus.$emit('updateResults', this.email); But then I get an error Evenbus undefined...

Comment: You should assign the event bus then to the Vue instance. like: Vue.prototype.$eventBus = new Vue(); then you can access it with this.$eventBus.$emit('firemyevent');